# Which version of neo4j for grails should I be using?

Tags: grails, neo4j, grails-orm

Which version of the neo4j plugin should I be using with grails?

The official grails site claims that version 2.0.0-M02 is the latest, but the associated documentation is from version 1.x.  Is there later documentation? Has much changed?

I'm interested in particular in how the node structure has been changed to represent the domain model. Is it now the case that labels are being used instead of SUBREFERENCE nodes now?

Comment: I'd use the 2.x plugin, it's pretty cool. And I hope Stefan updates the docs soon.

Comment: I've decided to roll my own driver, as without documentation for 2.x I don't know how it is representing my app into the database, and that makes it impossible to run cypher requests against it.

Comment: @DrJoe, what version of Grails are you using? When you said you'd roll your own driver, do you mean write your own Grails GORM <-> Neo4J code?  How are you intending to do that, spring-data-neo4j?  I'm using Grails 2.4.3 and his plugin example is broken (doesn't compile) in 2.x and has run-time exceptions in v1.  No decent documentation to work through is painful, so we're trying to determine potential alternatives.

Comment: It's 2.4.3. I've decided not to use GORM at all, and to instead roll my own code using spring-data-neo4j. It's been a few days of struggle working how how it all hangs together. I've managed to get the repositories auto-wiring now, but I still can't work out how to enable @Transactional annotations against neo4j.